# a mensagem não é atualizada quando enviada para mais de uma tela

Tags: java

Explico melhor na imagem. Mas é o seguinte. Tenho um bt para add frutas. sempre que uma fruta é adicionada, abre-se uma nova tela para ela. mas vem o problema: TODAS AS FRUTAS ADICIONADAS DEVEM APARECER EM TODAS AS TELAS, PORÉM TODAS AS FRUTAS, SÓ APARECE NA ÚLTIMA TELA ADICIONADA.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
public class JFrameEnvia extends JFrame {

static DefaultListModel model;
static JList jListReferencia;
static JScrollPane scrolList;
private JButton btadicionar;
private JPanel contentPane;
static JTextField areaNomeFruta;
int k = 0;

public JFrameEnvia() {
    super("tela add fruta");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 558, 312);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    btadicionar = new JButton("adiciona");
    btadicionar.setBounds(147, 11, 89, 23);

    btadicionar.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (!areaNomeFruta.getText().equals("")) {
                model.add(k, areaNomeFruta.getText());

                new TelaFruta().setVisible(true);
                k++;
            }
        }
    });

    contentPane.add(btadicionar);

    areaNomeFruta = new JTextField();
    areaNomeFruta.setBounds(10, 12, 103, 20);
    contentPane.add(areaNomeFruta);
    areaNomeFruta.setColumns(10);

    model = new DefaultListModel();
    jListReferencia = new JList(model);

    scrolList = new JScrollPane(jListReferencia);
    scrolList.setBounds(335, 54, 89, 151);
    contentPane.add(scrolList);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new JFrameEnvia().setVisible(true);
    ;
}

public class TelaFruta extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;
static DefaultListModel modelList;
static JList liste;
JScrollPane scrolList;
private JButton btEnviarNomeFruta;

public static void copiarItensSelecionados(JList jListReferencia) {
    modelList = (DefaultListModel) liste.getModel();
    for (Object sel : jListReferencia.getSelectedValuesList()) {
        if (modelList.indexOf(sel) == -1) {
            modelList.addElement(sel);
        }
    }
}

public TelaFruta() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 558, 312);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setLayout(null);
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    System.out.println("tela");

    modelList = new DefaultListModel();
    liste = new JList(modelList);

    scrolList = new JScrollPane(liste);
    scrolList.setBounds(335, 54, 89, 151);
    contentPane.add(scrolList);

    btEnviarNomeFruta = new JButton("enviar o nome das frutas");
    btEnviarNomeFruta.setBounds(234, 230, 198, 32);

    btEnviarNomeFruta.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            TelaFruta.copiarItensSelecionados(JFrameEnvia.jListReferencia);
        }

    });

    contentPane.add(btEnviarNomeFruta);
}
```

}

Comment: Possível duplicata de [valor não é atualizado quando vai para outro JFrame](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/189551/valor-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-atualizado-quando-vai-para-outro-jframe)

Comment: Não é recomendado ter mais que um jframe na aplicação, o correto é criar apenas um e para subtelas criar jdialogs.

Comment: exemplos? pode me dar

Comment: Aqui mesmo tem várias repostas com exemplos: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jdialog

Comment: mas se eu trocar os JFrames seguintes por JDialog a informação será atuliada nas telas?